# Code generation - design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, asterisk

I need to generate a script (asterisk OBD script), kind of shell script, with routines and sub-routines, from a set of inputs for the script. I need to do it in Java. Which design pattern to use for code generation? I tried template pattern and command pattern but was halfway confused and stopped. any idea, design, doc and others would be appreciated.

below is the sample code. 
note 1: <> are the params supplied as input.
note 2: nested dtmf information, depending the subroutine is coded.
let me know if more explanations are required.

```
[<context_name>]
exten => answered,1,set(actionid=actionid:${ACTIONID})
same => n, wait(1)
same => n, read(input,<file path>/<file>,1,,,10)
same => n, gotoif($[${input}=1]?1pressed,1)
same => n, gotoif($[${input}=2]?2pressed,1)
same => n, noop("No/Invalid input")
same => n,hangup

exten => 1pressed,1,read(inputsub,<file path>/<play1>,1,,,10)
same => n, gotoif($[${input}=1]?1subpressed,1)
same => n, gotoif($[${input}=2]?2subpressed,1)
same => n, noop("No/Invalid input")
same => n,hangup
same => n(1subpressed),playback(<file path>/<playsub11>)
same => n,hangup
same => n(2subpressed),playback(<file path>/<playsub12>)
same => n,hangup

exten => 2pressed,1,playback(<file path>/<play2>)
same => n,hangup


exten =>h,1, set(CDR(userfield)=$actionid)
same => n, hangup
```

Comment: Totally depends on the specification of the code generation process. If you just need to spit out always-the-same units of code, you´ll go for a different technique as opposed to generating code that is a parser for a given grammar, for example. So without knowing what the input is, and what the generated script should cover, nobody can offer a good answer. It might be a good idea to post the code you´ve tried so far, no matter how confused it left you behind.

Comment: I have edited the question providing a sample output script code to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for what you need to do, but in model-driven projects I have implemented a couple of extensive code generators based on EMF models using Eclipse M2T (http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/m2t/), although it was called openArchitectureWare back then.

Your input would need to be available as a model though, and you'd need to familiarize yourself with the languages that are used within M2T to generate code like XPand